# How to put a range variable inside VLOOKUP in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm doing a VLOOKUP function between two columns, using folloving macro:

```
Sub ExcelJoin()
On Error Resume Next
Dim Dept_Row1 As Long
Dim Dept_Clm1 As Long
Dim LastRowA As Long
Dim LastColO As Long

Set currentsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
ctr = 0


LastRowA = currentsheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastRowO = currentsheet.Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Table1 = currentsheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRowA)
Table2 = currentsheet.Range("O2:O" & LastRowO)


Dept_Row1 = currentsheet.Range("B2").Row
Dept_Clm1 = currentsheet.Range("B2").Column
For Each cl In Table1
  currentsheet.Cells(Dept_Row1, Dept_Clm1).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1], R2C15:R14C15, 1, False)"
  Dept_Row1 = Dept_Row1 + 1
  ctr = ctr + 1
Next cl

End Sub
```

But as far the number of rows in a range R2C15:R14C15 is unknown, i should put R14 as a variable, using LastRowO. But i have some problems with synthases, cause i don't know how really put this variable into VLOOKUP in a correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work:

```
currentsheet.Cells(Dept_Row1, Dept_Clm1).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1], R2C15:R" & LastRowO & "C15, 1, False)"
```

btw, there is no need to use loop `For Each cl In Table1`. You could apply formula to entire range *in one line of code*.

Change:

```
For Each cl In Table1
  currentsheet.Cells(Dept_Row1, Dept_Clm1).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1], R2C15:R14C15, 1, False)"
  Dept_Row1 = Dept_Row1 + 1
  ctr = ctr + 1
Next cl
```

to

```
currentsheet.Range("B2:A" & LastRowA).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1], R2C15:R" & LastRowO & "C15, 1, False)"
```

Comment: Thank You! It works perfectly with " & LastRowO & "! About the loop, i'm just not sure, because I think "B2:A" & LastRowA could be wrong

Comment: Ale, actually they are the same. As follow up from your code `Table1 = currentsheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRowA)` and then you're looping throught each cell in range `Range("A2:A" & LastRowA)` in line `For Each cl In Table1` and add formula to corresponding value in col `B`. In that case it's simplier to use `currentsheet.Range("B2:A" & LastRowA).FormulaR1C1`:)

Comment: Ah, I get the logic, you are right. But if i do a range substitution it returns me an empty column B instead of Vlookup, that's why i thought that could be something wrong there.